# How to determine the highest value in a list of properties

Tags: c#

I have a class such as this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Value1 {get; set;}
    public int Value2 {get; set;}
    public int Value3 {get; set;}
    public int Value4 {get; set;}
    ...

    public string AnotherValue {get; set;}
}
```

In reality there are around 10 properties, all holding values. What I'm trying to do is to determine the property with the highest value. I initally thought this would be a trivial task, but so far, I've only managed to come up with two ways to achieve it, and neither of them feel very elegant.

My first way is to simply test each value:

```
int runningValue = myClass.Value1;
if (myClass.Value2 > runningValue)
    runningValue = myClass.Value2;
// etc...
```

The second way was to use reflection to do the same thing, but in a loop of all the properties - although this isn't ideal because there are properties such as AnotherValue that I would need to exclude.

My question is: is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: You should be using some sort of collection in this case

Comment: Is there a pattern for the name of the properties that you need to compare? Your 2nd approach is the best way to go forward, would it be possible to make a meta list of property names that you would need to compare and use that list to filter the properties

Comment: @OldProgrammer I'm afraid I don't have any control over the structure of the class.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you use a collection or list instead of an object to carry the same data type.

But for your question, you can try to use *reflection*  `GetProperties` to get all you want to compare data from your object.

`x.PropertyType == typeof(int)` can make sure what type you want to get on your question you might want to compare with int.

```
MyClass a = new MyClass()
{
    Value1 =  10,
    Value2 = 11,
    Value3 = 12,
    Value4 = 14
};

a.GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(int) )
    .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.GetValue(a)))
    .Max(x=>x);
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UPc7rD)

Comment: I don't have control over the structure of the class. Thanks for this; however, this is using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

A collection would definitely make this task much easier. If you decide to go that route, you could still have properties for Value1/Value2/etc.., however you would have to implement the get/set accessors to look in the collection for the data. If you know at which index each value will be at, it could be as simple as

```cs
private List<int> Values = new List<int>(3);

public int Value1 {
    get => Values[0];
    set => Values[0] = value;
}

public int Value2 {
    get => Values[1];
    set => Values[1] = value;
}
```

If you really wanted to go the reflection route... you could create an attribute to specify which properties to include when determining the max

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class IncludeInMaxAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class MyClass {
    [IncludeInMax]
    public int Value1 {get;set;}

    [IncludeInMax]
    public int Value2 {get;set;}

    public string AnotherValue {get;set;}

    public int GetMax()
    {
        int maxValue = int.MinValue;

        foreach (var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.GetCustomAttribute<IncludeInMaxAttribute>() != null)
            {
                maxValue = (int) prop.GetValue(this);
            }
        }

        return maxValue;
    }
}
```